# Django - Foreign Key must be an instance

Tags: django, django-models

I've a model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ModelA(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I need to insert the data into this model. I've an endpoint hosted which provides me the following data `{'phone':XXXXXXXX, 'user_id':123}`.

Now when I insert the data into this model like

```
obj = ModelA.objects.create(phone=data['phone'], user = data['user_id]
```

It throws an error saying

```
Cannot assign "u'123'": "ModelA.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Agreed, since because with django orm you can interact in terms of objects and not numbers. Hence I first found the object of the User and then created ModelA object.

```
user_obj = User.objects.get(id=data['id']
modelobj = ModelA.objects.create(phone=data['phone'], user = user_obj
```

Till here its all working fine.

Now, my question is that is there any other way of assigning/creating `ModelA` object directly using `user_id` not `User` object, since it first involves quering User Model and then inserting. Its like an extra read operation for every ModelA object created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I keep getting votes for an answer that is wrong. If the database you are using has actual integrity checking, you can just use *attr_name*_id to insert the related object.

Wish I could just delete it. Look at the answer below.)

Basically, you can't do that. Django's ORM is expecting an object and not just a key. It's the price to pay to have an extra layer of abstraction that is supposed to check for integrity at the application level, instead of the DB-level.

If performance is a problem (and in the general case it isn't), you can make the read operation of the User object as light as possible. The `only` function will return a queryset of objects, forcing the select to retrieve only the id column, which is surely indexed.

```
user = User.objects.only('id').get(id=data['user_id'])
obj = ModelA.objects.create(phone=data['phone'], user=user)
```

Comment: Not completely correct, just for future people who are going to read this question there is a way, you can do `ModelA.objects.create(phone=data['phone'], user=user_id) #in case ModelA related to user via user id, for other fields you can do user_name`

Comment: The correct code is: ModelA.objects.create(phone=data['phone'], user_id=1)

Comment: Just for clarification, Vlad's second comment works (i.e. you can disregard the code in the first comment).

Answer (score 17):

As can be seen in my historic comments, the accepted answer is not really correct.
So as [@yekta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277186/yekta) requested I re-submit my comments:

To create the parent model, use integer value like:

```
ModelA.objects.create(phone=data['phone'], user_id=1)
```